# Separate model and UI view model in Spring (sort of MVVM in Spring)

Tags: java, mvvm, spring-mvc

I would like to start a discussion on separating pure model and UI model in Spring 3.

By pure model I mean main object/objects that I retrieve from database, let's say some "user account". It contains enough info to display it in HTML view or to pass it to web service.

By UI model I mean all the auxillary stuff I need in UI to work with that object. E.g. if a "user account" has "state", then I need to fetch all the "states" from the database for, say, a combo box. The views are tricky and in some cases they require more information, in others - less. It would also be nice to be able to alter some lists by adding items like "Select all", which is pure UI stuff (and not quite conveniently done from view template).

I heard there's so called Model-View-ViewModel pattern, which seems to address these issues, but I have never tried its implementations.

The solution I use right now is to break logics into two services - one for pure model and one for UI model. It looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="app/user_accounts/{id}")
public String getUserAccount(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    service.getUserAccount(id); // Gets main object and puts it into model
    presenter.formUserAccount(); // Gets all classifier for main object's properties
    return "user_account";
}
```

What I dislike about this is that the view and its so-called view model are not attached to each other. I can call presenter.formUserAccount() and return totally unrelated view name.

Another approach I see is similar to Spring controller annotation. We have classes annotated as @ViewModels and methods which map to view names. An interceptor finds and executes these methods before rendering a certain view. These seems elegant enough, but requires much code writing.

How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have been thinking about this in the context of Grails, which is based on Spring MVC. My approach is to use Command Objects as View Models as it gives you the data binding and validation features that you would want in a View Model.  With Command Objects you can abstract your "Pure Model" (or Domain Model) out of your View by using the Command Objects to map the view properties onto you domain objects.